# Should System.nanoTime() in Java be explicitly casted to a double for game loop?

Tags: java, game-loop

I am writing a game loop in Java and trying to calculator deltas. When attempting to get the current time, the following does not give me an error in my IDE. However the function returning a double, where are System.nanoTime() return a long. Why is this not an error?

```
private static double getTime() {
    return System.nanoTime() / 1000000000;
}
```

Is explicitly casting to a double better?

```
private static double getTime() {
    return (double) System.nanoTime() / (double) 1000000000;
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the first function, the division will be integer division and the result of the division will be casted to `double`. It is thus equivalent of  `return (double)(System.nanoTime() / 1000000000);`

So for example if the `System.nanoTime()` gives a value of `142154`, the `getTime()` will return 0, because in integer division the fractions are ignored. `142154 / 1000000000` returns a value of `0.000142154` which will thus be rounded to zero.

The second function will on the otherhand perform an floating-point division, which will keep the fractions and thus be more precise. You don't have to cast both of the arguments to `double`, only one of them.

The reason the first version of `getTime()` will not give an error is that Java implicitly casts `long` to `double` because `double` is *more precise* data type than `long`. For the same reason `int` can be implicitly casted to `long` (but not other way around!).